# Python, unittest: Can one make the TestRunner completely quiet?

Tags: python, unit-testing, verbosity

Is there a way to make [unittest.TextTestRunner](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner) completely quiet, meaning it never prints to output on its own? Even at `verbosity=0` it prints results when done.

I want to process the TestResult object returned by the runner before anything is printed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TextTestRunner has a `stream=sys.stderr` in its constructor:

```
def __init__(self, stream=sys.stderr, descriptions=1, verbosity=1)
```

Change it to a null stream.

```
result = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream = open(os.devnull, 'w')).run(alltests)
if len(result.failures) or len(result.errors):
    print "Sorry."
```