# Python unittest output only on test failures

Tags: python, python-unittest

Is there a way to write (or run) a set of Python `unittest` tests so that there is no output *except* when there is a test failure?

For example, if `tests/mytests.py` contains some `unittest` tests, then running `python3 test/mytests.py` will only output to stdout (or stderr) if there is a test failure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.  I was able to combine the techniques in the answers to these two questions to get it to work:

[Python, unittest: Can one make the TestRunner completely quiet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157456/python-unittest-can-one-make-the-testrunner-completely-quiet)

[argparse and unittest python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265522/argparse-and-unittest-python)

You can uncomment the `test_should_fail()` test to verify what happens when a test fails.

```py
# mymodule.py

def myfunc():
    return True

import unittest
import os

class TestMyFunc(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_myfunc(self):
        self.assertEqual(myfunc(), True)

    # def test_should_fail(self):
    #     self.assertEqual(True, False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    alltests = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestMyFunc)
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    result = runner.run(alltests)
    if len(result.failures) or len(result.errors):
        print('There were failures or errors.')
```